# getting module dependencies from a perl distribution file?

Tags: perl, cpan

Given a perl distribution file, e.g. a file like `Archive-Zip-1.30.tar.gz`, what is the modern way to determine what prerequisites (i.e. other perl modules) the distribution needs?

I imagine the procedure goes something like:

1. unpack the archive
2. if a `Makefile.PL` file is found, then ...
3. if a `Build.PL` file is found, then ...

or maybe there's a module?

I should add that I'm interested in perl code to list the dependencies.

Update: I guess the answer is just to look at the `META.json` or `META.yml` file which should be included in every dist file.

Update2: Not every dist file has a META file. See my answer below for how to generate them.

Comment: CPAN deal with dependencies

Comment: pm-deps can do this https://metacpan.org/module/pm-deps. and you can get dependencies in META.json or META.yml files in your archive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I've been able to determine. Perhaps this clarifies my question.

1. If there is a `META.yml` or `META.json` file in the dist, you can get the module requirements from either of those files.
2. If there is a `Makefile.PL`, you can generate `META.yml` using:

   `perl Makefile.PL; make metafile`

   This will create `META.yml` in the `DISTVNAME` subdirectory. The `DISTVNAME` is defined as `{distname}-{distversion}`, i.e. for the dist `Archive-Zip-1.30.tar.gz` the `DISTVNAME` is `Archive-Zip-1.30`.
3. If there is a `Build.PL` file you can generate a `MYMETA.yml` file using:

   `perl Build.PL`

   The `MYMETA.yml` file will be created in the current working directory.

Older dist files won't have the META files. For example, the dist `Digest-1.00.tar.gz` [(link)](http://backpan.perl.org/authors/id/G/GA/GAAS/Digest-1.00.tar.gz) from 2001 only has a `Makefile.PL` file whereas the latest version `Digest-1.17.tar.gz` [(link)](http://backpan.perl.org/authors/id/G/GA/GAAS/Digest-1.17.tar.gz) includes a `META.yml` file.

This raises the question of how to accurately get at the `DISTVNAME` for dists which have a `Makefile.PL` file.

It seems that the best way is to run `perl Makefile.PL` and then parse the `Makefile` for a line that looks like:

```
DISTVNAME = ...
```

Very kludgy, but I'm not sure there is a better way.

Comment: Yes, that all seems correct.  Beware that the META and MYMETA files are not quite the same.  The latter describes dependencies as configured on your this machine, which may or may not be what you actually want.

Both `Makefile.PL` and `Build.PL` can generate META files.  I usually use the `distmeta` command for that.

But I'm still not really clear on the context of your question.  If you explain *why* you want to know about the module dependencies or *what* you plan to do with that data, then perhaps I can give you a more helpful answer.

Comment: I want to fully understand the schema of dist files, modules, module version constraints, etc. Prerequisites are constraints on module versions. My view is that given a dist file there should be an algorithm to determine what these constraints are. My next question is going to be: given a dist file, how do you determine what module-versions are "defined" by the dist file. I want to build up my understanding of this realm piece by piece.

Comment: [CPAN::Meta::Spec](https://metacpan.org/module/CPAN::Meta::Spec) is useful for study.  Most dist tools predate the spec, so it is not completely authoritative.  But the spec does give you a sense of how distribution metadata probably **should** be presented and processed.

Answer (score 2):

If you are in a situation where you need to think about a module's dependencies, then the META may not be enough.  In my experience, you usually need to know the entire dependency graph to do anything useful.  I'm not aware of a separate tool that will recursively analyze module dependencies, although you might find one on CPAN and could certainly cook it yourself.

Dependency information can also be found through the [MetaCPAN API](https://github.com/CPAN-API/cpan-api/wiki/API-docs), so that's another way to get the data without actually having to fetch all the modules from CPAN and look at their META files.

If you build your dependency graph based on "latest" modules from CPAN, then beware that it may change over time, because new releases to CPAN can change their dependencies at any time.

For a more visual answer, you could create a free account on [Stratopan.com](https://alpha.stratopan.com) and pull `Archive-Zip-1.30.tar.gz` into a repository there.  Then you could look at the graphs it produces of all the dependencies. [This](https://alpha.stratopan.com/thaljef/Apple/Leopard/graphs) is an example of such graphs.  [Disclaimer: I operate Stratopan.com]

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Stratopan looks very interesting, and, in fact, looks like it is related to the original reason why I asked this question :-)

Comment: I just posted an answer which may clarify somewhat what I am asking.

Answer (score 1):

Judging from how Dist::Zilla's --listdeps command works, I would guess you look for 
https://metacpan.org/module/CPAN::Meta::Requirements and in there for
requirements_for().